# what do i need to use to get 2 words out of a string? regex or explode?

Tags: php, regex, explode

Here is the string:

```
Added:  yesterday Closing: 17.02.2013
```

there may be variations of the above string such as :

```
Added:  today Closing: 04.02.2013
Added:  16.01.2013 Closing: 15.02.2013
```

I need to be able to get the "yesterday" and "17.02.2013" or "today" and "04.02.2013" or "16.01.2013" and "15.02.2013"

right now here is what i got..

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $initialDate);

echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
echo $pieces[3]; // piece2
echo '<br/><br/>';
```

but i get only "today" and "closing" , should have got the closing date, but its not working..

should i have done it using regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

explode can be used, in this case.  The keys and values come in pairs with the key preceding the value, so look for the keyword and then take the next string as the value. I'd probably return it as an array of the form (key1 =>value1, key2=>value2,)

When it works explode is likely to be faster than regex, but the speed isn't a big factor in most cases.

Edit: the example has multiple spaces between the elements, these need to be removed first or empty items skipped in the result.

Comment: in my example when i use echo $pieces[3]i dont get the second date i am looking for

Comment: it's because you have multiple spaces between the pieces, you will need to remove those first.  Regex is the easiest way to do that. use preg_replace

Comment: when using the result be sure to check for things like missing keys and missing values.

Comment: having some trouble to remove the extra space, this does not seem to work 'echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $initialDate);'

Answer (score 1):

There are too much spaces in your string to make it in the order you expect.

To keep with explode(), do not *blindly* address an array member with guessed number but `print_r($pieces);` first, then notice the right number, then use it

If the number of spaces can vary - regexp is the only [sensible] choice. Though it can be combined with regexp by using simple `$pieces = preg_split('#\s#',$initialDate);`

Comment: empty elements can be removed from the result. regex isn't really needed here.  Even with the regex split they still need to validate the result in case the input isn't key: value, but something like key: key:

Comment: thanks for the advice, used print_r to get the adress.. it was piece [1] and piece [2]. here is the output am getting.. 

today Closing:04.02.2013

guess i will have to use preg_replace as @Peter has suggested..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regular expression

```
$string="Added:  today Closing: 04.02.2013";
$result = preg_match_all("/([a-z A-z])*day|((\d{2}\.){2}(\d{4}))/", $string,$match);
print_r($match[0]);

 output
 Array ( [0] => today [1] => 04.02.2013 )
```

pattern "/([a-z A-z])*day/" match string ends with day
 pattern "((\d{2}.){2}(\d{4}))" matches date of the form (dd.mm.yyyy) or (mm.dd.yyyy) 
  [Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vwsZvk)

Answer (score -1):

Exploded is just fine, as long as the input does not change. Regex are fine too, but they usually make the code hard to read and slow down the application. It seems you are missing the double-spaces in your text, that creates a empty string in your result of explode. Checkout the contents with var_dump, print_r or better use debugging.

```
foreach(explode("\n", $str) as $line)
    print_r(explode(' ', $line));
```